# Prove or disprove that if $X$ is independent of $Y$, then $E[X|F]$ is independent of $E[Y|F]$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

> If $X$ is independent of $Y$, then $E[X|F]$ is independent of $E[Y|F]$.

If the above statement is not correct, how to construct a counter example to disprove it?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 8):

Definitely incorrect.  Let F = X+Y.  Suppose X and Y are IID normal.  Then E[X|F] and E[Y|F] are both linear in F, and hence perfectly correlated.

Comment: Yup. As soon as X and Y are i.i.d. (not necessarily normal), E(X|X+Y)=E(Y|X+Y)=(X+Y)/2.